# Trying to sort array of objects by street address but the sorting is coming back mixed up, not sure how to adjust my logic to sort it properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a React/TypeScript component where I'm trying to sort an array of Location objects by their street address in ascending or descending order.

Right now I have a simple inline sort function that compares the street address value and based on whether the selection was ascending(a > b) or descending(b > a) it compares and returns the list in that order.

The unforeseen issue that I'm running into is that because the street address property comes back as a string, I think the numerical value of the house number is not being compared correctly and so my list is returned with a seemingly randomly ordered sort.

For example ascending would return:

```
13151 LAKE SHORE DR

2001 ROGER ST S

5101 SHANNON AVE S STE 2B

2001 ROGER S ST STE B2

10520 ITALY S AVE
```

Where the expected return I would imagine would be all of the addresses that begin with a house number 1, then number 2, 3 and so on.

This is how my sort functions looks right now:

```
// Function for asccending order
    if (sort === 'alphaAsc') {
      filteredLocations = filteredLocations.sort((a, b) =>
        a.addressLine1 > b.addressLine1 ? 1 : 0
      );
    }


// Function for descending sort
    if (sort === 'alphaDesc') {
      filteredLocations = filteredLocations.sort((a, b) =>
        b.addressLine1 > a.addressLine1 ? -1 : 0
      );
    }
```

Comment: Your sort function is incorrect. The comparator must return a number that's negative when `a` should go before `b`; positive when `b` should go before `a`, and zero when the ordering is already correct.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
// Function for asccending order
    if (sort === 'alphaAsc') {
      filteredLocations = filteredLocations.sort((a, b) =>
        a.addressLine1 > b.addressLine1 ? 1 : a.addressLine1 < b.addressLine1 ? -1 : 0
      );
    }


// Function for descending sort
    if (sort === 'alphaDesc') {
      filteredLocations = filteredLocations.sort((a, b) =>
        b.addressLine1 > a.addressLine1 ? -1 : a.addressLine1 < b.addressLine1 ? 1 : 0
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For each filter function you'll want to return 1 if the object b should come before object a, return -1 if object a should come before object b and 0 if the objects are in the correct order.

```
if (sort === "alphaAsc") {

  filteredLocations = filteredLocations.sort((a, b) => {

  if (a.addressLine1 < b.addressLine1) return -1;
  if (a.addressLine1 > b.addressLine1) return 1;
  return 0;

  });
};

if (sort === "alphaDesc") {

  filteredLocations = filteredLocations.sort((a, b) => {

  if (a.addressLine1 > b.addressLine1) return -1;
  if (a.addressLine1 < b.addressLine1) return 1;
  return 0;

  });
};
```